# InvalidArgumentException View [admin.home] not found. http://127.0.0.1:8000/home

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I defined a route in Laravel

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\HomeController;

Route::get('/home', [HomeController::class, 'redirect']);
?>
```

Which executes the redirect function from the HomeController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Models\User;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function redirect() {
        if (Auth::id()) {
            if (Auth::user()->usertype == '0') {
                return view('user.home');
            } else {
                return view('admin.home');
            }
        } else {
            return redirect()->back();
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Now when I login with admin access, it gives me the following error

> InvalidArgumentException
> View [admin.home] not found.
> http://127.0.0.1:8000/home

I have created a folder called `admin` in the `views` folder, and I have created a file called `home.blade.php` in it: `views\admin\home.blade.php`.

But if I login with user access, the blade file will be displayed without errors.

What can I do?

Thanks for taking the time to read this question.

##### Update:

The error image is shown below

[image: error image]

Comment: Could you please try `php artisan view:clear` and `php artisan cache:clear` once ?

Comment: @OnkarManvelikar I did this but the result did not change

Comment: @MortezaRg Please, could you share an image of the full error? (Just add the image, do not remove anything you added to your question). Can you tell us if the path is exactly `PROJECT_ROOT/resources/views/admin/home.blade.php`?

Comment: @matiaslauriti Yes, of course I put the photo. My path is exactly what you said.

Comment: im pretty sure you forgot to add the `.blade.php` extension or the file is misplaced in the laravel folder structure

Comment: @mentamarindo Thanks, it was fixed, there was a problem writing the blade phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the blade file really exists in the path then the problem occurs by caching. Open the terminal and run: `php artisan view:clear`.

Make sure that your file is a `blade.php` file. It often happens that blade is forgotten in the name. i.e. `admin.php`.

Also make sure that the file is placed in the correct path inside `resources\views`.

Answer (score 1):

try `php artisan optimize:clear`

Comment: What is it going to change? Add more information as, running `optimize:clear` will do nothing.